# Download parsing code from server and execute it in app: security?

Tags: python, security

I have a question regarding the security of my software.

My software downloads RSS feeds from the Internet, parses them, and does things with it. These things include following the url of the posts stored in the RSS feeds, and parsing the original web page of the posts in certain cases.

Of course, the websites providing the RSS feeds often change the design of their websites, which makes my parsing code obsolete each time they do that. I run regular tests that are supposed to flag the changes, but sometimes I miss it.

Each time a change happen, I have to fix the code, repackage the software, make the installers, push the new version to the server, etc (for Mac, Windows and Linux). Just because the parsing part had to be updated. My app is written in Python.

I was thinking about putting the parsing scripts on my server, and make my software download the scripts if the parsing methods changed. But that would imply downloading code from a server, and executing it on the fly.

Is it secure to do something like that? Is there another way?

EDIT:

It should have been more explicit. My software is a PyQt app, a more or less standalone app that the user downloads and install. It's local to the user. The software downloads the RSS feeds from the user's computer. However, the software contacts *my* server (I control it) to perform a few things: create an account for the user if he doesn't have one, send feedback on the most read RSS feeds, etc.

When I update the software, I have a script to automate most things like building the installers and all, but there are always suprises (like SSL libraries updated on the OS side or any other weird thing), so I'd like to minimize the number of builds. Also, the user has to manually update the software on his side (and we know the user is lazy...)

Comment: To clarify: the software does run only on servers *you* control? Or is it a library you ship to end-users which will need to manually update? If the former, it just sounds like a problem in your devops workflow and can be fixed by automation, e.g. a CI server which does the packing, making of installers, and pushing of code. (You could do that locally simply with a script which does all that, but CI servers are good to have.)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. See my edit. My devops is more or less automated (but I gratefully accept name of CI servers).

Comment: Well then… just have your server do the downloading and parsing entirely…?